# How can I find the underlying file type in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, windows

In *nix system there is a command called 'file', which can tell you the underlying type of a file. Say, if you rename a binary executable's name into foo.txt, or you rename a mp3 file into .txt, the system will always tell you the real type of the file. But in Windows, there seems no such functionality, if you rename an executable into .txt, you cannot execute it. Can anyone explain to me how this is done in *nix system, and how can I find the real type of a file using C++, especially in windows, where I cannot use std::system("file blah")?

Comment: It's a heuristic algorithm that examines the first few (or few hundred) bytes of a file looking for a "magic string".  Many types of files contain a fixed sequence of bytes early on.  See [List of file signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) on Wikipedia.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: Actually you can execute any compatible binary in Windows regardless of its extension, only Window's Shell (explorer) prevents it. Most of commercial games' actual executable is not an .exe at all.

Comment: I wrote some applications to do maintenance work for certain custom database, there are different versions of history data with different format and different extension name. I actually have already finished the application by using extension names to determine file's version, yet this makes me wondering about the file command, so I was wondering how can I determine file's real type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File utility uses libmagic library. It recognises filetype parsing "special" fields in the file.
Of course, you can program by yourself recognition of some formats, but sometimes this requires plenty of work. E.g. when you try to differentiate between different formats of MP4.

Developers of that library did pretty huge amount of work. So it's adviced to use their results if you  want  to get god results in saying what type format you deal with.(this is a big sphere, really, and if knowing what type format you are working with,better rely on them then on your code)

File utility - http://www.darwinsys.com/file/
You can download source code and see how really many different recognition types they use.
Download archive file-4.26 -> magic -> Magdir

Personally  I had luck with compiling file 4.26 on Windows ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/

**Caution**
 It's merely a convention that files of certain formats should have predefined signatures and it's true almost always and helps identify formats of files properly. 
If it's not point of concern, you can surely trust signature. But just keep in mind that anyone having enough knowledge and wish can open a file in hex editor and playing with bits make another format of file.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX ***file*** command uses heuristics. There is a database of magic numbers, usually in **/usr/share/file/magic** and **/etc/magic/** that allows you to add new file "types" to be recogized by the file command. It simply probes the file to look for magic numbers (signatures) in its contents.

UNIX traditionally doesn't have the same type of file extension and type associations that Windows does, although Linux is accumulating that in recent times.

I would think on Windows you'd want to at least check the file extension association, to be correct. But even within a given extension (such as .txt) the individual program may perform its own heuristics. Example, notepad has to make an educated guess at the character encoding when it opens a file. Raymond Chen wrote a good read in his blog about it [The Old New Thing - The Notepad file encoding problem, redux](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The command [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) is suggesting that the type information is saved to an external place for further usage. It is also mentioning magic numbers, which is refering to [file signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).

Being 100% sure of a file type is theorically impossible since there is no precise rules around what a certain type should contain. Even if they were such rules, it would be possible to alter the file in a way to make it look like another one. While both signatures and extension can give you a good idea of what the type actually is, you still need to face the possibility of dealing with a wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

Even in Unix/Linux, the system doesn't actually definitively know a file's type.  The "file" program makes an educated guess by comparing the file's contents against a database of patterns that characterize a variety of common file types, but it's no more than a guess — it doesn't know about all possible file formats, and it can be wrong about the ones that it does know.

It's entirely possible to write a program like "file" for Windows; it doesn't depend on any special capabilities in the OS.  [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) provides a Windows port of the "file" program, for example.

The issue of renaming a program to have a `.txt` extension is unrelated to the "file" program.  That comes from the fact that Windows decides whether a file is executable based on its name (specifically, its extension), whereas Unix/Linux decides whether a file is executable based on its permissions — *not* its contents.  If you `chmod a-x` a program on a Linux system, the system will consider it non-executable, just like if you remove the `.exe` extension from a program on Windows.